# FlowType not installing with Brew

Tags: homebrew, flowtype

I can't get FlowType to install on Mac OS using brew. I typed:

```
$> brew update
...
$> brew install flow

Error: You must `brew link objective-caml' before flow can be installed

$> brew link objective-caml

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/objective-caml/4.02.1_2... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/Weak.S.3o
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.

$>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this? I tried installing Flow through brew and it all went fine. Perhaps things have changed since March?

Comment: Try `npm install flow-bin --global' http://flowtype.org/docs/getting-started.html#_

Answer (score 0):

Please Try change Permission
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 0):

The official installation method for flow is locally per-project using `yarn` (or npm).

`yarn add --dev flow-bin`

OR
With `npm`:

`npm install --save-dev flow-bin`

See the full instructions at https://flow.org/en/docs/install/